# Ubuntu stops responding to any action

Tags: ubuntu, ram, crash

I use ubuntu and found it really frustrating that it stops working really frequently. The circumstances are:

1. Opened Android Studio WITHOUT any emulators (I mean device emulator, I use real devices for debugging).
2. Opened Chrome with 4-5 tabs. 
   Bug reproduction scenario is as simple as it is:
   open one or two more tabs in Chrome, then Chrome goes grey and entire system stops responding to any input event. REALLY rarely it happens so I can open console and kill Chrome processes, but not anytime. Only thing what's left is Alt+PrintScreen+REISUB, which reboots the system.

My PC's specs are:
4Gb DDR2 RAM
Quad Core Intel CPU
Radeon R9 270x video

Are 4Gb not enough, or there is another reason for such behavior? What's for Windows, it does not crush entirely when some app starts consuming too much memory, it just closes the app, so goes for Android, btw. So, my questions are:

1. What can be the cause of my suffering(unresponsive Ubuntu)?
2. If it's RAM, are there some kind of apps that'll help the system to handle such situations correctly?

UPDATE:
I looked at the limits.conf file and found the following info:

```
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
#

#*               soft    core            0
#root            hard    core            100000
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#ftp             -       chroot          /ftp
#@student        -       maxlogins       4
```

I'm suspecting, that 100000 Kb limit is the reason. Am I right?

Comment: to verify if its low resources, run `top`  and then open up chrome and watch its behaviour. You could be genuinely running out of memory, or you could simply have a buggy version. Is your system fully updated?

Comment: yes, I login almost everyday and update everytime the system prompts me to

Answer (score 0):

Try to run with `--disable-gpu` once and see:

```
google-chrome --disable-gpu
```

Comment: sounds like workaround rather than solution, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I kinda SOLVED the problem, though the main question is still up. 
How I solved it: I just created 4 Gb SWAP file and that's it. Also, I opened system monitor and saw that I really was out of memmory when trying to launch heavy apps like Android device emulator alongside Android Studio and Chrome. So, OK, now I dont experience sudden "dead freezes", but still I really want to know, why there is no protection mechanism? Windows, for example, (as far as I know and saw for all those years of using it) never lets any app consume all memory, which causes system to stop responding. Can't I set some kind of barrier or limit of memory usage, like in Android, when system starts killing background processes?